# Question about how the optimal rate of two-qubit pure state interconversion is calculated

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163) [0], the optimal rate of interconversion between pure states is calculated on the bottom of page 7.  Basically, it is argued that since the entanglement cost and distillable entanglement are equal for pure states, it follows that we can calculate the optimal rate of interconversion between any two pure states as follows: first calculate the distillable entanglement of the initial state (this tells you the rate you can convert to Bell states), then calculate the entanglement cost to the final state (so the rate you can take Bell states to the final state).

My question is very simple: why is this optimal?  How do we know there isn't a more efficient path that takes you 'directly' between the two pure states, without having to convert to maximally entangled states first?

[0] Plenio, Martin B., and Shashank Virmani. "An introduction to entanglement measures." arXiv preprint quant-ph/0504163 (2005).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since entanglement cost and distillable entanglement are the same for pure states, we can go back and forth between any state and the maximally entangled state and any other state without loss. If you had a better protocol converting $\psi$ into $\phi$, you use it, then convert $\phi$ back into *more* copies of $\psi$ (since the original protocol was reversible, and yours is better), and then repeat.  This way, you could create an infinite amount of entanglement from almost nothing, and we know this is impossible.